# What are the origins of the two Latin names for boron, borium and boracium?

Tags: etymology, science

On Latin Wikipedia, there are a number of chemical elements with two Latin names, e.g. boron being *borium* and *boracium*. (Another example being nitrogen: *nitrogenium* or *azotum*.)

What is the etymology of *borium* and *boracium* and in what context should I use which?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about these two, or all of them?  It might be better to ask about one at a time.

Comment: @Nathaniel Ok, let me ask about boron, then. I was thinking there might be a trend, i.e. one historical name and one Latinized name from the modern name.

Comment: Many elements (including boron) weren’t known before modern times, because they don’t appear in elementary form in nature.

Comment: @chirlu Even more reason that they should have one name and not several.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=boron) gives this description for the etymology of *boron:*

> Originally called boracium by Humphrey Davy because it was drawn from boracic acid.

So that form was originally used by the discoverer of boron. I think it is fair to assume that *borium* is just a simple Latinization of *boron.*

*Azote* was the original name coined for the element nitrogen, so its use is similar to *boracium* for boron, though additionally it is used as the term for the element in some other languages (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen#History_and_etymology)). *Nitrogenium* is also presumably just a Latinization of the English name.

So, at least for these two, it seems to be a preference for an older name for the element (though not a classical Latin one) versus Latinization of the modern English name.